# Core Image filter "CIDepthBlurEffect" not working on iOS 11 / Xcode 9.0

Tags: core-image, ios11, xcode9

I can't get the new `CIDepthBlurEffect` to work. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a known issue?

Below is my code in Objective-C:

```
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kCIImageAuxiliaryDisparity, @"kCIImageApplyOrientationProperty", nil]];

CIImage *disparityImage = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData options:dict];

CIFilter *ciDepthBlurEffect = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIDepthBlurEffect"];
[ciDepthBlurEffect setDefaults];
[ciDepthBlurEffect setValue:disparityImage forKey:@"inputDisparityImage"];
[ciDepthBlurEffect setValue:originalImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
CIImage *outputImage = [ciDepthBlurEffect valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

EAGLContext *previewEaglContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:previewEaglContext options:@{kCIContextWorkingFormat :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCIFormatRGBAh]} ];

CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:disparityImage fromRect:[disparityImage extent]];

image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimg];

CGImageRelease(cgimg);
```

Comment: Does it work on iOS 10?

Comment: No, It's this filter is only supported on iOS 11.

Comment: Just stumbled across this. I see below it was resolved with a later beta but it's hard to see how it could work since you're never even using `outputImage`. i.e. this will return a render of the depth map, not the blurred image.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved with the release of Xcode 9 beta 2 and iOS 11 beta 2.

Comment: What was your issue before, when I apply the filter the wrong part of the image is blurred was that what you saw?. I have the latest Beta so I'm also not sure if it's the code or the OS.

Comment: Make sure you scale the disparity image.

Comment: Any idea where I get more info on scaling the disparity image?

Comment: If you're using the CIDepthBlurEffect filter, then the disparity image is automatically scaled up. if you're not then use the CIEdgePreserveUpsampleFilter.